# System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled - Azure WebAPI

Tags: c#, azure, exception, azure-web-app-service, webapi

I've experienced that the site I'm working on suddenly started to throw OperationalCanceledException. It seems to been started approx 25 May without no known changes to the site.

Does anyone have experienced the same thing? Could it be any changes in Azure lately that could have that effect? could A new version of any browser have that effect (for example Google Chrome seems to have some releases approx 24-25/5)?

It seems only affects webapi-endpoints. Have not heard any complaints from end-users, so I don't know how serious it is, but it shows up in logs as below.
The things in common are that it only seems to affect webapi-endpoints (starting with `/api/*` for us)

```bash
*2022-06-14T19:00:29,Error,***************,*******,******,0,9760,45,"System.Object : Unhandled Exception at /api/search/autocomplete
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.<ReadAsAsyncCore>d__17`1.MoveNext()

...omitted some of the stack traces, but it ends with this...

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()                                                
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)                                                
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()                                                
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.<>c__DisplayClass285_0.<ExecuteStepImpl>b__0()                                             
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)                                               
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)",*
```

Comment: can you provide the code so that we can investigate further

Answer (score 0):

After dig into this issue, I found the exception may occur because of API call doesn't respond.

> System.Object : Unhandled Exception at /api/search/autocomplete System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.

The issue happens **when the API call gets timeout**. To avoid this issue, you can change your **[HttpClient.Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=netcore-3.1)**.

```cs
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
```

Make sure to check your code if any of your process taking long to complete. You have to wait for completing that task. Use **`HttpClient.Timeout`**  for wait to complete the task.

You can use the **[OperationCanceledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operationcanceledexception?view=net-5.0)** class in your API to know when/where the exact issue happens.

#### Reference

- Operation Cancelled Exception [Link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/578605/systemoperationcanceledexception-the-operation-was.html) & [Link 2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/988799ad-f517-458e-b725-bef1fac61026/systemoperationcanceledexception-the-operation-was-canceled-exception?forum=aspgettingstarted)

Comment: Thanks for input! The strange thing is that its started throwing this exception from one day to another. The application is running in Azure and there has not been any known code changes. The question is if there could be any external changes (changes in Azure, browsers etc) that could cause this?

Comment: There is no specific changes in azure or browser.

Comment: check your api call with postman once