# Authorize for Azure AD groups in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, authorization

I am trying to use authorization on specific page views in controllers with [Authorize(Policy = "nameOfPolicy")] but I keep getting "Access denied" even though I have access to the Azure AD group that I have entered in my policy.

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Get the scopes from the configuration (appsettings.json)
        var initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
        

        // Add sign-in with Microsoft
        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))

            // Add the possibility of acquiring a token to call a protected web API
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)

            // Enables controllers and pages to get GraphServiceClient by dependency injection
            // And use an in memory token cache
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
            .AddDistributedTokenCaches();
        
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("it", policy => policy.RequireClaim("groups", "Azure group ID here"));
        });
        
        // Register AadService and PbiEmbedService for dependency injection
        services.AddScoped(typeof(AadService))
                .AddScoped(typeof(PbiEmbedService))
                .AddScoped(typeof(PowerBiServiceApi));

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        // Enables a UI and controller for sign in and sign out.
        services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
        
        // Session/cookie variables etc

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
        
        
        // Loading appsettings.json in C# Model classes
        services.Configure<AzureAd>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                .Configure<PowerBI>(Configuration.GetSection("PowerBI"));
        
        // Add the UI support to handle claims challenges
        services.AddServerSideBlazor()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSession();
        
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

And in my controller this is how I try to use the Authorize:

```
[AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
[Authorize(Policy = "it")]
public Task<IActionResult> Index()
```

Comment: It is possible by adding Authorize attribute at controller level or action method level. 

    [Authorize(Roles = "group1,group2")]
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        // Action methods
    }
    [Authorize(Roles = "group1")]
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        // Some Action method logic
    }

Answer (score 0):

> To authorize for Azure AD groups in asp.net MVC.

I have followed the below steps and able to authorize.

1. Create an APP in Azure AD and register the App.

[image]

2. Using the ID tokens in authentication for the App.

[image]

3. Set the RedirectionUrl in azure for the App from the authentication tab.

[image]

Choose the ASP.Net MVC application from Visual studio templates and install the below NuGet packages.

`NuGets`

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI
Microsoft.Identity.Web
```

In Startup.cs class make the below changes to register or configure the services of Authentication

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuartion.GetSetion("AzureAd"));
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
```

And you need add  `app.UseAuthentication ()` method along with `app.UseAuthorization()` in `startup.cs` class.

[image]

And you need to use the TenantId , ClientId and RedirectionUrl in the Settings.Json file.

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "Project",
    "ClientId": "",
    "TenantId": "",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**launchSettings.Json**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:42313",
      "sslPort": 44302
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MVC_APP": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:41222",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Authorize attribute need to be add at the controller level.

```
[Authorize] 
public class HomeController : Controller
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I have done. What I would like is further authorization per action in a controller for specific AD groups by using a policy checking on these groups.
For example if a smaller group of AD tenants should be able to access a view that not all users should be able to access.

Comment: This can be done with Role based access Control (RBAC), you can create a role and allow all the users of the tenants to that group, this helps to have access to only that group of tenants and deny to others.

Comment: Is this set in the App service Access control (IAM)? 
Will this role assignment only be created for the app service?
It says the Add Role assignment is disabled, but guessing that has something to do with my user permissions for the Azure subscription. 

However, I have role "Contributor", but if I try to use [Authorize(Roles = "Contributor")] above an action, it says Access denied even though I have that role.

Comment: Check the resource you are trying to access, and also check that your role assignment is valid for the App service. And the role assignments can be done at different levels like Subscription level, resource group level.